# Checkbox value stored and inserted multiple times

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have a  program where i need to register questions. A question can have 1 or multiple right answers, as checked in the method checkTaskType().
All ints are declared in the start of the code. 
Code runs fine and works, problem is that if i want to register multiple questions without closing the form, the value from previouse checkbox will be registered as a correct answer on the next question.

-- Dont mind DB design, thats a temporary solution

```
    //Method for insert to DB
    private void InsertQAData()
    {
        using (var con = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText =
                @"INSERT INTO task(tasktext, alt_1, alt_2, alt_3, alt_4, alt_5, illustration_link, task_type, alt_1_correct, alt_2_correct, alt_3_correct, alt_4_correct, alt_5_correct)
            VALUES (@taskText, @alt_1, @alt_2, @alt_3, @alt_4, @alt_5, @illustration_link, @taskType, @corrAlt1, @corrAlt2, @corrAlt3, @corrAlt4, @corrAlt5);";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@taskText", txtQuestion.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alt_1", txtAlt_1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alt_2", txtAlt_2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alt_3", txtAlt_3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alt_4", txtAlt_4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alt_5", txtAlt_5.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@illustration_link", txtLink.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@taskType", taskType);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@corrAlt1", corrAlt1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@corrAlt2", corrAlt2);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@corrAlt3", corrAlt3);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@corrAlt4", corrAlt4);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@corrAlt5", corrAlt5);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            lblInserted.Show();
      }

    // Method for checking if a question has 1 or multiple answers
    private void checkTaskType()
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            count += 1;
            corrAlt1 = 1;
        }
        if (checkBox2.Checked)
        {
            count += 1;
            corrAlt2 = 1;
        }
        if (checkBox3.Checked)
        {
            count += 1;
            corrAlt3 = 1;
        }
        if (checkBox4.Checked)
        {
            count += 1;
            corrAlt4 = 1;
        }
        if (checkBox5.Checked)
        {
            count += 1;
            corrAlt5 = 1;
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            taskType = "oneAlternative";
        }
        if (count > 1)
        {
            taskType = "multipleAlternatives";
        }
    }
```

Comment: how are you loading your questions?, why don't you uncheck all the checkbox before proceeding with followed by questions?

Comment: When is `checkTaskType()` called? What is the functional meaning of `corrAlt2` (and similarly named variables)? How is something registered as being a correct answer? This question lacks a lot of information on what the code is trying to achieve. Please add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can understand the problem.

Comment: forgot to add, i have a method that unchecks all checkboxes and their values. However even if the checkbox is unchecked, their values from previous will be registered

Comment: checkTaskType() is called on btn_continue, along with some other validations. The meaning of corrAlt is that a checkbox inserts value 1 to DB if it is checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling the `checkTaskType()` call a method `ClearResult()` like:

```
private void ClearResult()
{
count  = 0;
corrAlt1 = 0;
corrAlt2 = 0;
corrAlt3 = 0;
corrAlt4 = 0;
corrAlt5 = 0;
taskType = string.Empty;
}
```

This will help you after a question filled and stored to DB, reInitalize the varibles to default state.

So

```
checkTaskType();
//fill DB with values
//...
ClearResult();
```